# OpenGL program doesn't stop taking input and doesn't display Output

Tags: c, opengl, output, infinite-loop

```
        //Program to implement Basic Incremental Algorithm
        //Working on ubuntu
      #include <GL/glut.h>
      #include<stdlib.h>
      #include <stdio.h>

       GLfloat x0,x1,y0,y1; //Input variables taken as global 
       int flag=1;   //variable for display1()
       void init(void)
        {
             glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
             glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
             glLoadIdentity();
             gluOrtho2D(0.0,500.0,0.0,500.0);
        }
        void PutPixel(GLfloat x,GLfloat y)
        {
             glBegin(GL_POINTS);
             glVertex2f(x,y);      //To display pixels on-screen
             glEnd();
             glFlush();
        }
        void display1(void)
        {
             if (flag==1)   
             {
                   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                    glColor3f(0.7,1.0,1.0);
                    GLfloat m,c,y;
                    GLfloat i;                   //BIA algorithm
                    m=(y1-y0)/((float)(x1-x0));
                    c=y1-m*x1;
                    for (i=x0; i<=x1; i+=0.01)
                     {
                          y=c+m*i;
                          PutPixel(i,y);
                      }
                    flag++;
              }
         }
         void Input()
         {
            printf("Enter the co-ods\n");
            scanf("%f %f",&x0,&y0);
            scanf("%f %f",&x1,&y1);
         }
         int main(int argc, char **argv)
           {
             Input();
             glutInit(&argc,argv);
             glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA);
             glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
             glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
             glutCreateWindow("BIA");
             init();
             glutDisplayFunc(display1);
             glutMainLoop();
             return 0;
            }
```

I have initailaized flag as a global variable in the beginning and set it to 1. flag is used in the display1() to ensure that it executes only once. This is just one way I was trying to ensure that the output gets displayed.
Can anyone, please HELP!

Why doesn't the program stop taking input ?

Comment: You haven't asked any questions.

Comment: the title was the question itself .

Comment: Maybe it was, but it doesn't reflect your problem. What makes you think input have been taken multiple times? Your `Input` function called only once. Clearly explain what actual problem you have, what results you expect and how results you getting are different.

Comment: Actually,its working now. Initially, my program wasn't displaying any output on the screen and it was becoming very frustrating for me. But now, it is. So the problem has been solved. I don't know how. Or which change bought about it. But its working for now. Thanks , it had become very frustrating in between

Comment: You draw only once. If you'll minimise window (or place other window above it) and then switch to it again, you would see corrupt picture. That could be the source of your problem.

Comment: In other programs,I have had similar problems where the cursor stays in the window which takes the input and nothing gets displayed on the other window. I am unsure about what you're suggesting. I am clueless about the modification I bought about in this program , but then, its finally working now.

Answer (score 0):

It's working. I'm still unsure about which edit or change bought about it. But it's working!! it's displaying some output